# How to optimize hibernate polymorphic query not to join all subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, optimization, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to optimize hibernate queries and faced the problem that hibernate makes more complicated queries than I expected.

I have a base class **WorkUnit** and several subclasses **CheckEmployee, Meeting, HomeCareRequest**  and  **WorkUnitAssignment** which points to **WorkUnit**.

Here are sketches of the classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORK_UNIT_ASSIGNMENT")
public class WorkUnitAssignmentEntity {
    private WorkUnitEntity workUnit;
    ...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "WORK_UNIT_A_WORK_UNIT_ID")
    public WorkUnitEntity getWorkUnit() {
        return workUnit;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "WORK_UNIT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class WorkUnitEntity  {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHECK_EMPLOYEE")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="CHECK_EMPLOYEE_ID")
public class CheckEmployee extends WorkUnitEntity {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "MEETING")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "MEETING_ID")
public class MeetingEntity extends WorkUnitEntity {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "HCIS_HC_REQUEST")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "HC_REQUEST_ID")
public class HomeCareRequestEntity extends WorkUnitEntity {
}
```

I want to load **WorkUnitAssignment** with **HomeCareRequest** only.
This is my query:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(WorkUnitAssignmentEntity.class);
DetachedCriteria dc = criteria.createCriteria("workunit", "workunit");
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("workunit.class", HomeCareRequestEntity.class));
```

Hibernate generate such sql:

```
select ... from WORK_UNIT_ASSIGNMENT this_, WORK_UNIT joinworkun1_, 
           HC_REQUEST joinworkun1_1_, CHECK_EMPLOYEE joinworkun1_2_, 
           MEETING joinworkun1_3_
where this_.WORK_UNIT_A_WORK_UNIT_ID=joinworkun1_.WORK_UNIT_ID and 
joinworkun1_.WORK_UNIT_ID=joinworkun1_1_.HC_REQUEST_ID(+) and 
joinworkun1_.WORK_UNIT_ID=joinworkun1_2_.CHECK_EMPLOYEE_ID(+) and 
joinworkun1_.WORK_UNIT_ID=joinworkun1_3_.MEETING_ID(+) and 
case
when joinworkun1_1_.HC_REQUEST_ID is not null then 1
when joinworkun1_2_.CHECK_EMPLOYEE_ID is not null then 2
when joinworkun1_3_.MEETING_ID is not null then 3
when joinworkun1_.WORK_UNIT_ID is not null then 0
end=?
```

This query has to extra joins to **CHECK_EMPLOYEE** and **MEETING**.
My question is how to configure hibernate not to make these joins.

I tried to change the inheritance to singe table and using secondary table in subclasses but result is the same.